# Nexus 5 whole battery drained in a single night

Tags: battery, battery-life, nexus-5

I charged my phone to 100% before going to sleep. I used it for only few minutes and found out my phone was off in the morning because all the battery was drained. I charged it and saw battery stat and it showed as:

[image]

It shows that the screen was totally off the whole night. What caused the battery to drain so fast?

Another stat view:

[image]

It is the first time this has happened.

Comment: It seems like your exchange services drained all the battery.
That bug was partially corrected with the last update to 4.4.2. Which OS version are you using?

Comment: My device shipped with version 4.4.2. I was using that service since the start but I am facing this problem only today.

Comment: Try to stop the service. It should stop the battery drain. You should also try to set the email "Sync Frequency" to "Automatic (Push)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using Exchange on serveral devices at the office (for testing) and what i noticed is that sometimes exchange services seem to drain alot of battery even when set to a low interval or push.

This typically happens when Exchange is trying to pull some data from the server but an error occurs. The end user (you) does not always see the error.

For me usually a reboot fixes the problem, worst case remove the Exchange profile and reinstall it afterwards.

Comment: This is exactly what happened with me. I also finally figured it out. Yesterday, I tried to sync my other account and there was an error which I ignored and carried on. That might have triggered the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open the email client, go to settings > The email ID you have configured > Inbox Check frequency

Change that setting to "Never" if you want to manually refresh emails or increase the duration for the refresh. That should fix the battery draining overnight.

Comment: The mail check frequency was `Automatically (Push)` from the beginning. I had no problem except yesterday, which drained the battery. Must be some bug in the Exchange service. I will update if the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you turn the display ON before unplugging the charging cord, the battery stays at 100% all night.  My guess is that it also helps if you charge during the day.