# Why "Services Exchange" drains my battery since Marshmallow update?

Tags: battery, battery-life, 6.0-marshmallow

I have a simillar problem since Marshmallow. Unfortunately, as suggested I did clear the cache and I did a factory reset but the problem persists... "Services Exchange" continues to drain my battery in less than 3h without using my phone at all, which never happened with Lollipop before. Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: Related (not posted for Android M): [Nexus 5 whole battery drained in a single night](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/64836)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! If you don't use a MS Exchange server for mail, you could simply go to *Settings › Apps*, select the "All" tab, scroll to the Exchange app (which is an extension to the Email app), and force-stop + disable it. Let us know whether that helps. In my experience, even with no Exchange account created, that stupid addon tries to contact some non-configured-account for mail every minute (no idea why).